# laravel - sum of time from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Welcome ! I made in function this query 
`$time= DB::table('notes') ->where('pilot_id', $id) ->sum('time');`

but i get format like this 120000 and it should be 1:20 how to get it?( hours:minutes)

Time is stored in database as "time" type

Comment: what is your time field data type ?, can you give one example value for time ?

Comment: field data type is time. Example stored in database: 01:20:00 -> 1hour 20 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$time = DB::select("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) AS total_time FROM notes WHERE pilot_id = ?", [$id]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($time);
exit;
```

Comment: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: still same. In view i should pass it as `{{$time}}` ?

Comment: first you store the result in a variable and than print it and see what query returns.

Comment: but i need to store it as time, can't do this as variable

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_time] => 01:20:00
        )

)`

Comment: so you finally get your result `01:20:00`. Now you just pass this data to view and print in view file

Comment: {{$time[0]->total_time}}

Comment: ok but if I use this `{{$time[0]->total_time}}` why it should be that 0 ? i need to sum it for each user not only for one so each user will have different sum of time

Comment: I give you solutions what you asked for. I can not do code for your entire business logic